# How to fetch all the batches for a query at one go using stored proc in azure SQL db?

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am trying to check if there are duplicates in a collection. New to stored procedures and azure database, so for now am trying to count distinct entries. If count distinct (column name) = count (column name), there are no duplicates, so I am trying to write a stored procedure for that. But azure retrieves 100 docs at a time only. I need the count over all the batches available.

I was able to get the count of distinct entries, but it shows the count for the first batch retrieved - which is 100. I need the count over all the batches.

```
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT DISTINCT VALUE r.column FROM root r',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(feed.length));
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

I expect the output to count the distinct entries in the collection. It should be 103, but the actual is 100 which is the number retrieved by azure at one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of FeedOptions pageSize property for queryDocuments is 100, which might be the cause of the issue. Please try to set the value to -1. The following stored procedure works fine on my side, please refer to it.

```
function getall(){
 var context = getContext();
  var response = context.getResponse();
  var collection = context.getCollection();
  var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

  var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM c';

  collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, {pageSize:-1 },
    function(err, documents) {
      response.setBody(response.getBody() + JSON.stringify(documents));
    }
  );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please accept as an answer if it helped.It will help other who have the same ASK.